Prometheus shows all k8s services except my custom app
I have a relatively simple task - I have a mock python app producing events (just emitting logs). My task is to prepare a helm chart and deploy it to a k8s cluster. And I did that. Created an image, pushed it to a public repo, created a helm chart with proper values, and deployed the app successfully. Was able to access it in my browser with port forwarding. I also included PrometheusMetrics module in it with custom metrics, which I can see when I hit the /metrics route in my app. So far, so good.
The problem is actual prometheus/grafana. I install them using kube-prometheus-stack. Both accessible in my browser, all fine and dandy. Prometheus url added to grafana connection sources, accepted. So I go to visualizations, trying a very simple query from my custom metrics, and I get "No Data". I see grafana showing me options from prometheus related to my cluster (all the k8s stuff), but my actual app metrics aren't there.
I hit the prometheusurl/targets, and I see various k8s services there, but not my app. kubectl get servicemonitor does show my monitor being up and working. Any help greatly appreciated. This is my servicemonitor.yaml:
ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: producer-app-monitor
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: producer-app
  endpoints:
  - port: "5000"
    path: /metrics
    interval: 15s

Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: producer
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: producer
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: app-0.1.0
  name: producer-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: producer
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app
  type: ClusterIP


Can you try setting up a port forward to your service: kubectl port-forward svc/YOUR_SERVICE_NAME 5000:5000 and then curling the endpoint in another window: curl -i localhost:5000/metrics. Are metrics being returned? Can you post a snippet of what is returned?

@JasonSnouffer if I port forward to 5000, I'll get a blank screen on "/", and 404 on /metrics. I port forward to 8000 to get it working with both routes. Is that a problem?

Yep that is definitely a problem. It means the issue is on the app side, not with Prometheus. The ServiceMonitor needs to point to a working endpoint that is returning Prometheus-compatible metrics.

Should your ServiceMonitor be pointing to port 8000 instead?

@JasonSnouffer I switched it to 8000, restarted, still doesn't see it. My prometheus is on 9090, my grafana is on 3000 (both port forwarded). My app is deployed on 5000, but I have to port forward to 8000 to see it in my browser. Networking isn't a strong suite of mine, I feel like I'm missing something basic here

Can you post your service object spec? Maybe its the selector label in the ServiceMonitor.

What do you mean by service object spec? This block in service.yaml?
spec:
type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
ports:
- port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
targetPort: http
protocol: TCP
name: http
selector:
{{- include "..selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
or this from values.yaml?
service:
type: ClusterIP
port: 5000
targetPort: 5000

kubectl get svc YOUR_SERVICE_NAME -o yaml

@JasonSnouffer https://pastebin.com/JwqYKUBL

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Please update the question to include (a) the configuration (Deployment?) that is maintaining the replica of Pods; (b) kubectl describe service/producer-app to see which Pods (if any) are being selected. There's an issue with the port too (as @JasonSnouffer suspects), until you can retrieve metrics using port forwarding against Pods, everything downstream is moot.
